# using [nsarray arrayWithObjects:]

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am using this to return

```
  return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:message, previousNum, nil];
```

When it outputs it always outputs like

```
 (
     Hello 22
 )
```

I would like to know how to remove the round brackets from the output

If anyone could help I would appreciate it

Thanking You

Comment: You are (implicitly) using the `description` function which is only intended for debug -- not production.  The presentation *is not* guaranteed to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your output is generated with `NSLog(@"%@", theArray)` or similar. In this case `NSLog()` calls the `description` method of `NSArray`, which returns a string that represents the contents of the array, formatted as a *property list*.

So the parentheses are not part of the array but part of the description output.

If you want a different output, you have to generate it yourself, for example

```
 NSString *str = [theArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

to create a string with all array elements separated by a newline character.

**ADDED:** A property list is a structured data representation used by Cocoa and Core Foundation as a convenient way to store, organize, and access standard types of data.
The `description` method of `NSArray` encloses the array in parentheses, and all elements are separated by commas (and a newline character). This format is described in [Old-Style ASCII Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001012-BBCBDBJE).

For more information about property lists, see the [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD).

Comment: Formatted as a property list - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for certain, but it looks like you want help turning an NSArray into an NSString.

This conversion from NSArray to NSString is done implicitly when outputting an NSArray using `NSLog(@"%@", array)` (or other such formatting methods). `NSLog` calls `[array description]` to convert `array` into an NSString.

You can create your own method for converting the NSArray to a NSString, or you can use something like `-componentsJoinedByString:`. With your array in a variable `array`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

will print `Hello, 22`.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [array componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

will print `Hello 22`.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

will print `Hello22`.